# Getting ControllerBase Operations into Mediatr Commands

Tags: c#, api, controller, cqrs, mediatr

I'm abstracting out my API logic in my controllers to Mediatr Commands and Queries. My POST and PUT endpoints get validated via standard .NET Core model binding validation, but the patchdoc for my PATCH endpoint needs to check the model state for validity in the controller. Since it's part of the ControllerBase I can't access that context anymore though.

How would you all recommend approaching this?

**Patch Endpoint**

```cs
        [HttpPatch("{valueToReplaceId}")]
        public IActionResult PartiallyUpdateValueToReplace(int valueToReplaceId, JsonPatchDocument<ValueToReplaceForUpdateDto> patchDoc)
        {
            var query = new UpdatePartialValueToReplaceCommand(valueToReplaceId, patchDoc);
            var result = _mediator.Send(query);

            switch (result.Result.ToUpper())
            {
                case "NOTFOUND":
                    return NotFound();
                case "NOCONTENT":
                    return NoContent();
                case "BADREQUEST":
                    return BadRequest();
                default:
                    return BadRequest();
            }
        }
```

**UpdatePartialValueToReplaceCommand**

```cs
public class UpdatePartialValueToReplaceCommand : IRequest<string>
    {
        public int ValueToReplaceId { get; set; }
        public JsonPatchDocument<ValueToReplaceForUpdateDto> PatchDoc { get; set; }

        public UpdatePartialValueToReplaceCommand(int valueToReplaceId, JsonPatchDocument<ValueToReplaceForUpdateDto> patchDoc)
        {
            ValueToReplaceId = valueToReplaceId;
            PatchDoc = patchDoc;
        }
    }
```

**(BROKEN) UpdatePartialValueToReplaceHandler**

```cs
    public class UpdatePartialValueToReplaceHandler : IRequestHandler<UpdatePartialValueToReplaceCommand, string>
    {
        private readonly IValueToReplaceRepository _valueToReplaceRepository;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;

        public UpdatePartialValueToReplaceHandler(IValueToReplaceRepository valueToReplaceRepository
            , IMapper mapper)
        {
            _valueToReplaceRepository = valueToReplaceRepository ??
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(valueToReplaceRepository));
            _mapper = mapper ??
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mapper));
        }

        public async Task<string> Handle(UpdatePartialValueToReplaceCommand updatePartialValueToReplaceCommand, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (updatePartialValueToReplaceCommand.PatchDoc == null)
            {
                return "BadRequest";
            }

            var existingValueToReplace = _valueToReplaceRepository.GetValueToReplace(updatePartialValueToReplaceCommand.ValueToReplaceId);

            if (existingValueToReplace == null)
            {
                return "NotFound";
            }

            var valueToReplaceToPatch = _mapper.Map<ValueToReplaceForUpdateDto>(existingValueToReplace); // map the valueToReplace we got from the database to an updatable valueToReplace model
            updatePartialValueToReplaceCommand.PatchDoc.ApplyTo(valueToReplaceToPatch, ModelState); // apply patchdoc updates to the updatable valueToReplace -- THIS DOESN'T WORK IN A MEDIATR COMMAND BECAUSE I DON'T HAVE CONTROLLERBASE CONTEXT

            if (!TryValidateModel(valueToReplaceToPatch))
            {
                return ValidationProblem(ModelState);
            }

            _mapper.Map(valueToReplaceToPatch, existingValueToReplace); // apply updates from the updatable valueToReplace to the db entity so we can apply the updates to the database
            _valueToReplaceRepository.UpdateValueToReplace(existingValueToReplace); // apply business updates to data if needed

            _valueToReplaceRepository.Save(); // save changes in the database

            return "NoContent";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same situation and solved it by letting ModelState out (changed code):

```
updatePartialValueToReplaceCommand.PatchDoc.ApplyTo(valueToReplaceToPatch); 

        //if (!TryValidateModel(valueToReplaceToPatch))
        //{
            //return ValidationProblem(ModelState);
        //}
```

Of course your missing the 'ModelState' validation this way.I would validate it through the Domain model.

Comment: Maybe I'm just not familiar with the syntax, but I'm not sure how you'd validate a json patch doc like that as it's only bits and pieces of the model. When I tried taking the `ModelState` param out, it fails really ungracefully when something invalid is sent through (e.g. trying to patch an int with a string). Honestly, I'm not a huge fan of the implementation I came up with either, but I'm not sure what would be better either.